# MS SQL Query to get all entries comming multiple times in table where some column value doesnt have entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just tried to formulate title as best as possible. So my case is as follow.

i have a table

```
venue_id | style_id | is_main
1        | 1        | 1
1        | 2        | 0
1        | 3        | 0
2        | 5        | 0
2        | 8        | 0
2        | 9        | 0
3        | 3        | 1
4        | 4        | 1
4        | 6        | 0
5        | 7        | 0
5        | 8        | 0
5        | 9        | 0
```

So i need to get only those venue ID, witch coming more then once and where is no is_main true entry.

So result should be contain venue_id's: 2 and 5

I would grateful for any suggestion how such query may looks like.

Thanks in Advance.

UPD: in my case with is_amin BIT value answer would be:

```
select venue_id
from table
group by venue_id
having cast(max(cast(is_main as INT)) AS BIT) = 0 and
count(*) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select venue_id
from t
group by venue_id
having max(is_main) = 0 and
       count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Looks good, In my case i got an error because is_main is data type BIT so i did updated bit and posted as update to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.venue_id FROM venue v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT venue_id FROM venue WHERE is_main=1) m
ON v.venue_id = m.venue_id
WHERE m.venue_id IS NULL
```

If you have many thousands of rows, it would be better to create a secondary table or a materialized view to be used in place of the nested SELECT.